# How To get value of column when it exist in content value of column by sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I want To get value of column when it exist  in content value of column by sql server 2016

For Example:

**Table1:**

```
Title1 
----
Jack
Benz
Volvoo
```

**Table2:**

```
    Description              Names
    ----                    ---------
  The Jack isnt A122           NULL
  Some  B1234 Benz             NULL
  This Volvoo Are C            NULL
  This Maria Are D             NULL
  Michael Jackson              NULL
```

example:

Search Row By Row From `table 1` in the row by row column `Description` in `Table 2` and get value and insert to cloumn `Names`

IF `Jack` or `Benz` Or `Volvoo` exist in `The Jack isnt A122` 
get `Jack` and Update column `Names` in  `Table 2`

```
    Description              Names
    ----                    ---------
  The Jack isnt A122           Jack
```

For `'Jack owns a Benz'` that matches 2 titles (Jack and Benz), update with either one of them.

For Other Rows in Table 2 same:

```
    Description              Names
    ----                    ---------
  The Jack isnt A122           Jack
  Some  B1234 Benz             Benz
  This Volvoo Are C            Volvoo
  This Maria Are D             Others
  Michael Jackson              Others
```

- The tables do not have primary keys.
- `Table1 (Title1)` is `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Under some simplistic / naive assumptions (that match the given data):

- The descriptions have only spaces and no other whitespace or connecting characters (dots, comma, question marks, dashes, etc.)
- Titles are single words (no spaces, no extra characters either).

We can use `LIKE` to check whether a description contains a title:

```
concat(' ', description, ' ') LIKE concat('% ', title, ' %')
```

to first check that the matches are according to requirements:

```
select s.description, coalesce(t.title, 'Others') as title
from table2 as s
  left join table1 as t
  on concat(' ', s.description, ' ')
     LIKE concat('% ', t.title, ' %') ;
```

and then do the update:

```
update s 
set s.names = coalesce(t.title, 'Others') 
from table2 as s
  left join table1 as t
  on concat(' ', s.description, ' ')
     LIKE concat('% ', t.title, ' %') ;
```

Test in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=134648e2b569e86d3bd7fd5f52a5f15e)

Comment: Thanks for solution  my friend. why double data for one value ?one null other correct value.